# ArrayList prints multipe times

Tags: java, hashmap

My problem is that when I run this code, everything in the ArrayList is printed about 3 times.

Here is the code you will need to see:

```
static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
static HashMap<String, Character> books = new HashMap<String, 
Character>();

public static void main(String[] args){
//      Title, Section
books.put("Harry Potter and the blank blank blank", 'A');
books.put("Harry Potter and the blank", 'Z');
books.put("Harry Potter ", 'Z');
books.put("Harry Potter and the blank blank", 'L');
findBook("Harry");
}

public static void findBook(String title){
list.clear();
for (String key : books.keySet()) {
  if(key.equalsIgnoreCase(title)){
    System.out.println(books.get(key));
  }
  else if (key.startsWith(title)) {
    list.add(key);
  }else System.out.println("Book not found");
    for(String bookTitle : list){
      System.out.println("Book: " + bookTitle);
  }
}
```

Please help, thank you so much!
-S1ant

Answer (score 0):

You have kept the `for` loop that prints the books within the one that finds and hence you get multiple prints. Move the for loop that prints out of that loop as in below:

```
static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
static HashMap<String, Character> books = new HashMap<String, 
Character>();

public static void main(String[] args){
//      Title, Section
books.put("Harry Potter and the blank blank blank", 'A');
books.put("Harry Potter and the blank", 'Z');
books.put("Harry Potter ", 'Z');
books.put("Harry Potter and the blank blank", 'L');
findBook("Harry");
}

public static void findBook(String title){
list.clear();
for (String key : books.keySet()) {
  if(key.equalsIgnoreCase(title)){
    System.out.println(books.get(key));
  }
  else if (key.startsWith(title)) {
    list.add(key);
  }else 
    System.out.println("Book not found");
  }
}

// Move this out of the above loop
for(String bookTitle : list){
  System.out.println("Book: " + bookTitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below for loop executes every time you try to find a book. Hence you are seeing multiple prints.

```
for (String bookTitle : list) {
    System.out.println("Book: " + bookTitle);
}
```

You can move the above for loop into main method and immediatly after the findBook method call.

Comment: Ok, but what if I want to make it more customizable? Like I wanted to add a method to add books, and I wouldn't call the findBook method in the code, I'd call it from the console. I also wouldn't have the books hardcoded in, I'd have them added from the console.